# Is primary key always clustered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, primary-key

Please clear my doubt about this, In SQL Server (2000 and above) is primary key automatically cluster indexed or do we have choice to have non-clustered index on primary key?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nope, it can be nonclustered. However, if you don't explicitly define it as nonclustered and there is no clustered index on the table, it'll be created as clustered.

Answer (score 12):

One might also add that frequently it's BAD to allow the primary key to be clustered. In particular, when the primary key is assigned by an IDENTITY, it has no intrinsic meaning, so any effort to keep the table arranged accordingly would be wasted.

Consider a table Product, with ProductID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY. If this is clustered, then products that are related in some way are likely to be spread all over the disk. It might be better to cluster by something that we're likely to query based on, like the ManufacturerID or the CategoryID. In either of these cases, a clustered index would (other things being equal) make the corresponding query much more efficient.

On the other hand, the foreign key in a child table that points to this might be a good candidate for clustering (my objection is to the column that actually has the IDENTITY attribute, not its relatives). So in my example above, it's likely that ManufacturerID is a foreign key to a Manufacturer table, where it is set as an IDENTITY. *That* column shouldn't be clustered, but the column in Product that references it might do so to good advantage.

Comment: The presence of identity in most cases means that there will be access to records by their identity, so the clustered primary key on identity field seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @C-F - that's not a reason to cluster. If you're querying based on that primary key, the its index will get you there. And possibly quicker, too, since it almost certainly will require fewer IOs to get through a relative narrow index compared to the full width of the rows in the clustered index.